# Call JavaScript function from asp.net checkbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a jQuery function as below which I want to be called on a checkbox click. When I use an `input type="checkbox"` it works fine. But I want to check/uncheck the checkbox from c# code(fillform()) and based on that the JavaScript function also has to execute

But if I set `runat="server"` or if I use `asp:checkbox` then the below function is not called. I tried using the below code for asp:checkbox as well as for input box in page_load, but the function is not called

C# code

```
Page_load
  {
    chkVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleVehicle();");

  } 
  FillForm
  {
    chkVehicle.Checked = ObjUR.HasVehicle;


  }
```

jQuery function

```
 function toggleVehicle() {
        if ($('#chkVehicle').is(':checked')) {
            $('#divVehicle :input').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'transparent' });
        } else {
            $('#divVehicle :input').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'gray' });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because asp.net appends some more stuffs to the ids, like ctl, contentplaceholder etc... something like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkVehicle`. Instead you can do this:

```
 function toggleVehicle() {
         var chkVehicle  = '#<%= chkVehicle.ClientID %>';
        if ($(chkVehicle).is(':checked')) {
            $('#divVehicle :input').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'transparent' });
        } else {
            $('#divVehicle :input').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'gray' });
        }
    }
```

or just assign a class name and select it using the className.

or use jquery attribute **[ends-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)** selector, which could turn out risky though since it does a wildcard match, and slower as well.

```
      if ($('[id$="chkVehicle"]').is(':checked')) {
       ....
```

or as @jsonscript suggests

```
chkVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleVehicle('#" + chkVehicle.ClientId + "');");
```

and

```
 function toggleVehicle(chkVehicle) {

        if ($(chkVehicle).is(':checked')) {
            $('#divVehicle :input').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'transparent' });
        } else {
            $('#divVehicle :input').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#divVehicle').css({ "background-color": 'gray' });
        }
    }
```

Also instead of using `onclick` attribute, bind the handler to the element.

```
  $(function(){ //DOM ready
       $('#<%= chkVehicle.ClientID %>').change(toggleVehicle);   

  });

   function toggleVehicle() {
         var $divVehicle = $('#divVehicle');
        if (this.checked) {
            $divVehicle.css({ "background-color": 'transparent' });
        } else {
            $divVehicle.css({ "background-color": 'gray' });
        }
        $divVehicle.find(':input').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   }
```

*Also use prop instead of attr if you are not using really older version of jquery. That will set these kind of properties better than attr*

Comment: An alternative to this method is to pass the id of the control into the javascript function
So your c# would be 
`chkVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleVehicle(" + chkVehicle.ClientId + ");")`

then your JS would be like
`function toggleVehicle(chkBoxId) { }`

Comment: @jasonscript one more thing is prop v/s attr. Have updated the answer. Till ur comment i dint notice the usage on inline `onclick`. :)

Comment: thanks a lot. if i click the checkbox manually the function gets executed. but when the checkbox value is set from c# code as shown in the post then this function has no effect. can it be achieved?

Comment: @user1616785 if u need to trigger it manuaally. ex for the last snippet you can trigger it ther only `$('#<%= chkVehicle.ClientID %>').`change(toggleVehicle).change();`

Comment: @PSL thanks a lot it worked nice. but i really didnt understand this line ; may i ask what does this mean ? .change(toggleVehicle).change();

Comment: @PSL Sorry if ask for your help here, but I really need a hand here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403503/jquery-how-to-split-table-cell-into-a-different-number-of-rows-from-column-to-co Again, I do apologize for commenting on someone else's question

Answer (score 1):

In this code:  `chkVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleVehicle();");`, chkVehicle is the Id of checkbox.

Make the id of the checkbox to "Static" because when .aspx page is render, it appends the other ids of dom to the controls id. The Static will prevent this change and id of checkbox will remain same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be the **Id selector #** of jQuery.
The Id get change for asp.net if you use `Master Page` or `User_controls`.
You can use static clientId mode to the control which will not change the id of your controls

Here is a good article for the same

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature