# Unable to uncheck checkbox with postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, postback

I've got several checkboxes which are used to hide and unhide asp.net panels, I've done this using C# which is why I needed the postback.

Now initially the panels are hidden and my code works fine when checked, but when I try to uncheck them they retain their values after postback and the panels are still visible.

Here's my code:

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxHideShow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbxHideShow_CheckedChanged" Text="Hide/Show Panel"/>
```

and code-behind:

```
protected void cbxHideShow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbxHideShow.Checked = true)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

If someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Actually much easier to achieve this using client-side JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394892/call-javascript-function-from-asp-net-checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator (`=`) where you should be using the equality operator (`==`).

```
if (cbxHideShow.Checked == true)
```

Better yet, omit the operator completely since `cbxHideShow.Checked` is a boolean already:

```
if (cbxHideShow.Checked)
```

Of course, you don't even need the `if` statement at all.  You could just do this:

```
protected void cbxHideShow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = cbxHideShow.Checked;
}
```